# Select 1 radiobutton out of three

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I haven't worked with radiobuttons previously in MVC project.
And now when since i'm working with it for first time, i seem to face a problem.

What I want to do is, there will be questions, and user can select one answer from the available answers. Each answer will have a radiobutton.

Here is my **model**

```
public class CreateAppointmentSelectOptions
{
    public Guid AppointmentId { get; set; }

    //question1
    [Display(Name = "Repeat invitation untill a common date is found")]
    public bool RepeatTillCommonDateIsFound { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Repeat times")]
    [Range(1,5,ErrorMessage="Repeat times must be between {1} and {2}")]
    public int RepeatTimes { get; set; }

    //question 1
    [Display(Name="Repeat invitation once")]
    public Boolean RepeatOnce { get; set; }

    //question 1
    [Display(Name="Do not repeat invitation")]
    public Boolean NoRepeat { get; set; }

    //question 2
    [Display(Name = "Cancel the invitation")]
    public Boolean CancelInvitation { get; set; }

    //question 2    
    [Display(Name="Plan appointment with my first available date")]
    public Boolean FirstAvailableCommon { get; set; }

    //question 2 
    [Display(Name="Plan with all participants available on the first available common date")]
    public Boolean OwnerFirstAvailableCommon { get; set; }       
}
```

and the **controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create_WhatIf(Guid appointmentId)
{
    var appointmentCondition = new CreateAppointmentSelectOptions
    {
        AppointmentId = appointmentId,
        RepeatOnce = true,
        NoRepeat = false,
        RepeatTillCommonDateIsFound=false,
        CancelInvitation = false,
        OwnerFirstAvailableCommon=false,
        FirstAvailableCommon = true
    };
    return View(appointmentCondition);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create_WhatIf(CreateAppointmentSelectOptions options)
{
    return View();
}
```

and the **view**

```
@model CreateAppointmentSelectOptions
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create_WhatIf";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>What If?</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create_WhatIf", "Appointment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AppointmentId)


    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>What would you like to do if a common appointment with all participants cannot be made after the first invitation?</h3>
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">              
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RepeatTillCommonDateIsFound,Model.RepeatTillCommonDateIsFound)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RepeatTillCommonDateIsFound)
                </div>               
                <div id="RepeatTimes">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.RepeatTimes)
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RepeatOnce,Model.RepeatOnce)&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RepeatOnce)
                </div> 
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.NoRepeat,Model.NoRepeat)&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NoRepeat)
                </div>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>What would you like to do if a common appointment cannot be made in the end?</h3>
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">         
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CancelInvitation,Model.CancelInvitation)&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CancelInvitation)
                </div>                             
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OwnerFirstAvailableCommon,Model.OwnerFirstAvailableCommon)&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OwnerFirstAvailableCommon)
                </div> 
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FirstAvailableCommon,Model.FirstAvailableCommon)&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstAvailableCommon)
                </div>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input class="btn btn-default" value="<<Previous" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next>>" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

This is view being rendered in browser currently
[image]
**Question**

(Well the editor below the question is something you can ignore.)
Why are all the radio button being selected by default? And what should I do in order to make sure that only 1 radio button can be selected for each question?

Answer (score 1):

Each group of radio buttons should be bound to the same property on the model. Currently, each radio is its own property and therefore in its own group. And they are all checked because the 2 arguments passed to it are the same so a comparison always returns true (for example, `m => m.RepeatOnce` and `Model.RepeatOnce` are equal therefore radio is checked).

Instead, you need to add 1 property on your view model the represent each group. For example, question 2...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question2Answer, "CancelInvitation")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question2Answer, "OwnerFirstAvailableCommon")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Question2Answer, "FirstAvailableCommon")
```

The second value is the value to be assigned to `Question2Answer` if the corresponding value is selected. (Here I am using a string, but you can also use an Enum)

When the form is submitted, you have to use the value in `Question2Answer` to populate the `CancelInvitation`, `OwnerFirstAvailableCommon`, and `FirstAvailableCommon` properties on the model. Likewise, if you display an existing entity, you have to populate the `Question2Answer` property on your view model before rendering the view.

--- Update ---

View Model would look something like this. In your controller, you need to populate it from the model...

```
public class CreateAppointmentSelectOptionsViewModel
{
    public Guid AppointmentId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Repeat times")]
    [Range(1,5,ErrorMessage="Repeat times must be between {1} and {2}")]
    public int RepeatTimes { get; set; }

    public string Question1Answer { get; set; } // should have a more meaningful name

    public string Question2Answer { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I like your answer but based upon your answer how would my ViewModel look?

Comment: I tried adding question1 and question2 with type string in my viewmodel. Now, when the form is submitted the value of question1 and 2 seems to be set to the id of the radiobutton selected. For example, if `CancelInvitation` is selected in question2, the question2 value on form submission becomes `CancelInvitation`. Isn't it possbible to set cancelInvitation value of viewmodel to be true and other values in question 2 to be false?

Comment: I don't think so. At the end of the day, the Razor view is rendering HTML. And HTML radio button groups pass a single text value to the server (they behave exactly the same as a select/dropdown box in that regard). You'll need to perform the extra logic to map this HTML behavior to your the model you send to the backend.

Comment: So, I need to manually check the value and set the properties to true or false, if I have three answer then that'll mean three if this then set this true and other false. And if there are five answer's then five times if value equals this then set this true and other false??

Comment: Correct. Typically, values that are suitable for display as a dropdown list or a group of radio buttons are stored as one property rather than several booleans (cannot have more than one selected at a time)... so this is generally less of a problem. If you need to store them separately you'll have to do a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the groupName for your radio buttons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: OP is using ASP.NET MVC, this solution is for Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CancelInvitation,Model.CancelInvitation,new { Name = "grp" })&nbsp;&nbsp;
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OwnerFirstAvailableCommon,Model.OwnerFirstAvailableCommon,new { Name = "grp" })&nbsp;&nbsp;
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FirstAvailableCommon,Model.FirstAvailableCommon,new { Name = "grp" })&nbsp;&nbsp
```

Comment: Will this work? Wouldn't this set the name of the radio buttons to "grp" and break databinding? Also because the first 2 arguments to `RadioButtonFor()` are the same, wouldn't all the buttons be checked?

Comment: your code is also correct but its requirement is different. My code will also work. it is bind the model property with column name

Comment: this worked but then when the form is submitted all the values are false, even the selected ones

Comment: Please ask another question for this.